# Limiting the base current to BJTs in Gate Driver circuits

Tags: mosfet, bjt, buck, low-power, gate-driving

I want to make an MCU operated buck converter with the lowest operating current possible since most electronic shops near me only offered buck converters with an operating current of 10 mA and above. To achieve that, I've come up with the design below for the MOSFET gate driver, however, some questions came into my mind when I placed the R1 resistor to limit the base current (I want to reduce current draw as much as possible since I will be relying on batteries to power this project); in the discharge phase (Q1 and Q3 ON, Q2 OFF) the **peak** saturation current for the Q1 transistor will shoot up for a moment because of the added current of the discharge from Q3, will the limited Ib prevent the discharge from happening as planned? Or in other words, should I account for the discharge current when I'm calculating the value of IBQ1(sat) and R1?
I do realize that increasing the value of R2 to avoid losses will greatly affect the Ton time of the MOSFET since the gate drive current is decreased (unless I use a Darlington pair or a BJT with high enough current gain which might have a poor frequency response) but that shouldn't be a problem since I will be satisfied with a turn on delay of 0.09 µs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsx7rf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Important Specs**:
PWM frequency from the MCU: 500 kHz (it has to be from the MCU because the stm32 that I'm using is very good at generating PWM without consuming much power).
MOSFET total gate charge: 63 nC.
Total maximum average current draw should be <10 mA  (as low as possible).
MOSFET used: IRF5305.

Notes :- I also did not find any reasonably priced MOSFET gate drivers which is why I decided making my own.

- the buck converter will only be running for a about ten seconds to power the MCU when it is awake and two servo motors with a total maximum draw of 0.34 A, the buck converter will be turned off once the MCU returns to sleep-mode.

Even if this design might not be suitable for this application, it would be very helpful if you could answer the questions above, if you had other concerns regarding the circuit feel free to share them aswell.

Comment: The whole topology there is just wrong for that kind of speed, in my hobbyist opinion (it's all I have.) And I've no interest in fixing it. The CE stage needs to be replaced, at minimum, with a CB stage, instead. But that would require a change in the output stage, as well. Anyway, best wishes with it.

Comment: The important is R2 affects turn on time of Q2 (so turning off of M1) and even gate voltage when M1 is off. It is becouse with this push-pull driver you will never pull gate to 12V. There will be always drop between 12V and gate about Vbe_Q2+R2*Ib_Q2 so you can see how this drop rises when you use a huge R2.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický yes very interesting remark,  I did actually face that issue when I tried building this circuit using lower quality components, but it shouldn't be a problem since the Vgs(th) of the Mosfet I'm using is still adequate for this circuit.

Comment: @jonk Yes that might be what I need actually , I'm going to do my research for that (even though the circuit will have to change quite a bit), thank your for the encouragement.

Comment: Start with 1st principles of Ic=CdV/dt and specs for ramp up time and V tolerance error and load R + C. 10 mA is tight for buck considering the charge current to ramp up and supply decoupling needed

Comment: @A.H.Z If you can get off of this poor arrangement, I might consider something. While you may be able to get by (with enough thinking and added speed-up bits and pieces) with common BJTs, it may help reduce overall complexity to use faster ones, too. Shoot-through is another problem -- especially because you want low power -- and given discrete parts this is more a matter of adding circuitry that can be adjusted/calibrated after construction. (Or *tweeked*.) I'm not sure there is a design for 500 kHz and discrete parts haphazardly composed that will "just work" with random junkbox parts.

Comment: @A.H.Z 90 ns turn on times aren't all that easy. That's over 130 million volts per second! A meager 100 pF requires almost 14 mA at these rates! Your load (FET gate) will matter a great deal! So there must be a process of refining your specifications, too.

Comment: Ok, consider Q1 is turning off slowly because off huge R1 (discharging its junction). This couses slow turning on of Q2 and also slow M1 off transition so R1 add a huge delay and I doubt you will reach 500kHz with high-ohm resistors. Advantage is if you gonna hold converter off most of the time the resistors will drain almost nothing with this topology (no current flow when 3v3 is off) so there is no reason to use high resistances.

Comment: @jonk I'm not sure I fully understand your reply here, but what I am getting from you is that I need to use BJTS that are designed for high speed switching (which is something that I'll definetly do) , as for the poor arrangement, I'll try my best to improve this circuit before deciding on which components to use.

Comment: @A.H.Z You mentioned, *"but that shouldn't be a problem since I will be satisfied with a turn on delay of 0.09 µs."* Just the rise-time alone (forget the delay for now) will require non-trivial analysis in order to achieve, given a FET gate as a load. If the delay eats into this, then so much the worse. I'm not sure how you can say that it shouldn't be a problem with such a wave-of-a-hand. I certainly could ***not*** say such things, anyway.

Comment: @A.H.Z List out your key requirements for your application. A blinkered (narrow) focus on this stage, which is merely one part of something much larger, will cause you to lose sight of the actual goals. So you need to start with the overall system design requirements and then, incrementally and painstakingly, break them down into section requirements. I don't think that's been done so I don't think you are in a position to provide appropriate specifications for this section, yet. But whatever they are, they will most certainly include details derived from the driven FET load requirements.

Comment: @jonk I've assumed that 90ns was a rather slow turn on time only in comparaison with commercial use gate driver ics which can do much better , in addition, after calculating the required drive current for the transistor to supply for a turn on delay of 90ns was 0.7 A , which, again, when put into perspective is a relatively low current when you compare it to what other driver circuits can do, here for example this one can drive 15 A in and out of the Mosfet (although I doubt it is adequate for low power applications ). 
     https://opencircuit.shop/Product/15A-400W-MOSFET-PWM-Module

Comment: No sol'n is in sight without reasonable energy limits you must impose in your ? along with a list of tolerances. E=1/2 CV^2+VI*t.  Efficiency, error, and ripple tolerance. Consider the Q of the switch and excess reactive energy and losses of same considering the short operation.

Comment: @A.H.Z Do you see specs on that module saying 500 kHz and/or 90 ns delay or any guaranteed rise/fall times? I must have missed it. I'm not saying you can't. And if you feel you can easily, "no problem," implement such a thing with the discrete components in the circuit you've shown us, all I can say is *good for you* and *I'd love to see and learn from your design and results*. Somewhere in all this I need to also bring you back to your "low power" desire, too. It seems to be lost in the noise. But frankly? You have serious boundary specs. I feel they need careful thought. If you don't, fine.

Answer (score 2):

"I want to make an MCU operated buck converter with the lowest operating current possible since most electronic shops near me only offered buck converters with an ***operating current of 10 mA*** and above."

Here is a part that can be used, lower quiescent current.
https://www.befr.ebay.be/itm/234047609405?hash=item367e531a3d:g:B6kAAOSwI8Jg0Neo

MPM3610 FEATURES

- 4.5V to 21V Operating Input Range
- 1.2A Continuous Load Current
- **200μA Low Quiescent Current**

Comment: I will definetly check it out.